# Connecting to external database in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I don't know whether this should be here or stack exchange. Seems like stack exchange is more for theoretical discussion so I am starting here.
I want to create a connection string in the web.config file for queries to a database residing at another domain. I can't seem to find a good article for what to put in the connection string, and how to set up the responding database and it's security so that it will accept the connection with the proper credentials passed and execute and return the query. Does anybody know of a good article for this? Thanks.

Comment: Which database are you using? If you're using a MS SQL server account (created in SQL server), you'll need to add the username and password for the SQL server account in the connection string, and also set integrated security to false (otherwise it will try to authenticate with the current windows user). You will also need to add the server and probably the port number as well. Try www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: External database..do you mean connecting to a database from an internet(public IP) or intranet(domain network)?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have examples on every kind of connectionstring, or at least the ones that matter plus a few that dont: 
http://www.connectionstrings.com/